# Keep one number after decimal point, not rounding

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I have a double variable in c#:
DoubleVar = 3.488;

I want to keep only one digit after decimal point, not rounding. For example:
3.4
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Your example does not have a decimal point in it, did you mean to include one?

Comment: Sorry I edited it

Answer (score 4):

Since you specified *"no rounding"*, and did not specify that this was being displayed as *text*. Then the following will *Truncate* to 1 decimal place

```
value = Math.Truncate(value * 10) / 10
```

<sub>***Note:*** with floats you are likely going to get artefacts anyway, as there are numbers which can't be represented in base 2.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Main()
{
    double val = 1.33;     
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.#}", val));
}
```

Comment: Tnx , I edited my question, can you help me with this?

Comment: double val = 3.488;     
var num = Math.Truncate(10 * val) / 10;
Console.WriteLine(num);